# Keras LSTM took a long time to start fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was created this model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

But it took a long time to start fitting (now its about 2 hours)
what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using a GPU? How big is the dataset?

Comment: Yes I use GPU. I have around 1M record

Comment: Where is the data being stored and how are you loading it in?

Comment: Try to increase the batch size